# PHP: how to update an html element I already printed once I get the value in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Is it possible to put some sort of placeholder in html that I can then fill with a value once I get it from PHP?

For example if I want to change the title of an html page based on the first result of a Mysql query that happens only later in the page, how can I do it?

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title> </title>
</head>

<?php $title = mysql_query() ?>

--> how to update now the <title> element of the page?
```

It happens to me often that I get things I need to print in html only later in the page rendering from PHP, is there a way (JS?) to do something like this?

Comment: How is the php content generated later in the page?

Comment: Get all the info before outputting any html, or look into a better design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Restructure your PHP and HTML so that the data you need for your page is extracted and stored before you start rendering the page. Your example becomes:

```
<?php
  // extract your `title` data
  $myTitle = "MyTitle";

?>

<html>
  <head> 
    <title><?php echo $myTitle; ?> </title>
  </head>
<body>
<!-- render rest of page... -->
```

Comment: Hi yes I know this, but I'm working on already structured complex project where is not possible to do so. I can also solve repeating the php code before, but I wanted a more clean solution without altering the system structure.

Answer (score 1):

See «Example #1 User defined callback function example» at http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: Thanks I did not think about the buffering, it's possibly the solution I know better and not involving javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do what you want i.e. render content to the page after the page is fully delivered as you have rightly pointed at

1. Ajax - Using dynamic javascript and XML there are many good tutorials for doing this
2. For inner elements using plain javascript and setting "innerhtml" property of the element.

Both approaches uses client side scripting and cannot be called a PHP implementation per-se

Comment: Thanks yes innerhtml with Javascript looks like a simple enough solution involving relatively simple javascript...thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would just put that php in the title...

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

But it could also be done with javascript:

```
document.title = "<?php echo $title; ?>";
```